# Trying to grab a random pic through JS but dosen't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, django

Hi guys I am a django developer and trying to grab a random img through JS in html like below

img works and it would randomly pick one from the ImageArray.

However, the path will be `<img src= '/static/%22%20%2B%20img%20%2B%22'>`.

Rather than something I want like `<img src= "{% static 'img/indexBg_1.png' %}" >`

And the error msg is : GET `http://192.168.7.64:8000/static/img/%22%20%2B%20pic%20%2B%20%22%20` 404 (Not Found)

Could anyone enlighten me to resolve this problem? Thx!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        ImageArray = new Array();
        ImageArray[0] = 'img/indexBg_1.png';
        ImageArray[1] = 'img/indexBg_2.png';
        ImageArray[2] = 'img/indexBg_3.png';
        var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 3);
        var img = ImageArray[num];
        var path = " <img src= '{% static '" + img +"'%}'>"  
        console.log(img)
        console.log(path)
        }        
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a Django template using JavaScript. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the path, it should be something like:

```
var path = window.location.href +'/static/'+ img;
```

but if you want to add image with that path inside div:

```
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.innerHTML=`<img src=${path} />`;
```

even better to do:

```
var path = window.location.href +'/static/'+ img;
var myimg = document. createElement("img");
myimg.src = path;
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(myimg);
```